# mysql injecting record to a table using a query

Tags: mysql, sql

First - this is a question asken in interview .

I have a table with two columns , `year` and `value`.

- Lets say that in the `year` column I have 18, 19, 20 and so on,
- and on the `value` column I have 0.024 , 0.036, 0.048 and so on ...

What they wanted me to do is from that table to create the same table on a monthly base, so now 18 is 216 (18*12) and 19 is 228.

But the main idea is that now i have a record for each month , so now the month column should be : 216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227 (one record for each month ), and so on for each year at the original table I should have 12 records for each month in that year .

The `value` column now should be updated relatively in the new  table so lets say i had for the year 18 and the value 0.024 a month: 216 value : 0.024 , month: 217 value : 0.025 and so on ...

If we do this via programming language a for loop can do trick but I don't know any similar thing to a for loop in sql ...

This is the input table : please run the snippet to see how it looks like

```html
<table>
<tr><th>year </th><th>value </th></tr>
<tr><td>18 </td><td>0.024 </td></tr>
<tr><td>19 </td><td>0.036 </td></tr>
<tr><td>20 </td><td>0.048 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>21 </td><td>0.060 </td></tr>
</table>
```

this is how the output should be :please run the snippet to see how it looks like

```html
<table>
<tr><th>month </th><th>value </th></tr>
<tr><td>216 </td><td>0.024 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>217 </td><td>0.025 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>218 </td><td>0.026 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>219 </td><td>0.027 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>220 </td><td>0.028 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>221 </td><td>0.029 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>222 </td><td>0.030 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>223 </td><td>0.031 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>224 </td><td>0.032 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>225 </td><td>0.033 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>226 </td><td>0.034 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>227 </td><td>0.035 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>228 </td><td>0.036 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>... </td><td>... </td></tr>
  <tr><td>... </td><td>... </td></tr>
</table>
```

imagine those snippets as the input and output of the problem ...

Comment: so value increase in `0.001` by month? Because I think month value should be `year value / 12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is interview question, I won't answer for you using MySql but with TSQL (it is very trivial to translate though and I leave this exercise for you)

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0df2/2/0)**

```
SELECT (tab.year * 12 + num) AS month
     ,value + 0.001 * num AS value
FROM tab 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),
                   (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11)) AS t(num)
ORDER BY 1;
```

How it works:

1) Get data from tab

2) Generate Cartesian Product with subquery of numbers 0 - 11, each row with each other

3) In `SELECT` calculate month as `tab.year * 12 + num` and value and add new aliases

4) Order by month

Second look that I didn't use any loop but my solution is 100% set based. To store it with second table I need only `SELECT ... INTO new_table_name...` (TSQL):

**EDIT:**

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae55c/1/0)

```
CREATE TABLE tab(year INT, value NUMERIC(10,4));

INSERT INTO tab(year, value)
VALUES (18, 0.024), (19, 0.036), (20, 0.048), (21, 0.060);

CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT (t.year * 12 + c.num) AS month
     ,t.value + ABS(t1.value-t.value)/12 * c.num AS value
FROM tab t
JOIN tab t1
  ON t.year = t1.year + 1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS num      UNION ALL    SELECT 1     UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2             UNION ALL    SELECT 3     UNION ALL 
            SELECT 4             UNION ALL    SELECT 5     UNION ALL 
            SELECT 6             UNION ALL    SELECT 7     UNION ALL 
            SELECT 8             UNION ALL    SELECT 9    UNION ALL 
            SELECT 10            UNION ALL    SELECT 11) AS c

ORDER BY 1;

SELECT *
FROM new_table;
```

Comment: Hi Lad, Im not familiar with the syntax `AS t(num)` can you point me to a documentation link? Looks like creating a temporal table on the fly.

Comment: Yup this is power of derived table, basically is the same as `SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL ...) AS t` so I add alias for subquery and column at the same time. **Of course translating it to MySql is 5min of work**, I want that author do this and learn sth.

Comment: Ok, I see it now, num is the `alias`. I was thinking on some weird recursive function.

Comment: hey, can you wallk me throgh ?

Comment: @Amitbe See updated answer, if you think about working with database as developer `JOIN types/SQL Syntax/Relational Fundamentals` are primer.

Comment: ok so let me see if i got the idea, you create a new table of size 12 with this statment : VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),
                   (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11) 
and the you call this table t and  the column name is num , then  at the select statment you creat a month column which is composed from each year multiplied by 12  + num and a value column which is created from the value columne from original table + 0.001 * num ...
then you just make a cross join between this two tables !... that is crazy ! did i got it wright ?

Comment: @Amitbe I do exactly what you've written. **This is not crazy, this is SQL ;)**

Comment: ok so now if i try to convert this query to mysql where will there  be any differnce ?
i guess only at the creation of table t ?

Comment: @Amitbe See yellow box in answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89193/discussion-between-amitbe-and-lad2025).

Comment: this is working but one more thing , when you create the value column by like this "value + 0.001 * num" , then the number is manually entered , you figure out the difference between the record and inserted it multiply by num , but i want the diffence to be automaticlly calculted , somthing like the difference between 0.024 and 0.036 divide by 12 and multiply by num ... matematicly : (abs(0.024 - 0.036)/12)*num , how can this be acheived ?